# Column default not setting to 0

Tags: sql

not sure why that set default line isnt working it looks exactly like the examples I've seen

```
ALTER TABLE PILOT ADD PIL_PIC_HRS INT;

ALTER TABLE PILOT ALTER PIL_PIC_HRS SET DEFAULT 0.0;

UPDATE MODEL 
    SET PIL_PIC_HRS = CHARTER.CHAR_HOURS_FLOWN 
    WHERE CREW.CHAR_TRIP = CHARTER.CHAR_TRIP;
```

Comment: (1) You are setting t he default in `PILOT` but updating `MODEL`.  (2) Your `UPDATE` is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes i just saw that lol. I changed it and the set default 0.0 still isn't being run the default is still null

Comment: @CameronChaffey What part of it isn't working? In your `update` you're setting the that column, the default does not apply even if `CHARTER.CHAR_HOURS_FLOWN` is null.